# RegEx.Replace fails with $0.00 in replacement string

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to do a simple replacement utilizing the static RegEx.Replace method and it fails if inside the replacement string I have "$0.00" or some sort of derivative of this.

Here is the code:

```
void Main()
{
    try
    {           
        string inputString = "[BEGIN-LOOP:DETAILS]this is what I want to replace[END-LOOP:DETAILS]";
        string replacementString = "some text $0.00";   
        inputString = Regex.Replace(inputString, @"(\[BEGIN-LOOP:DETAILS\])(.*?)(\[END-LOOP:DETAILS\])", replacementString, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
        Console.WriteLine(inputString);     
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Output of the failed RegEx is:

some text [BEGIN-LOOP:DETAILS]this is what I want to replace[END-LOOP:DETAILS].00

It should be

some text $0.00

Comment: I don't know a lot about regex, but do you have to escape the '$'?  What exactly happens when it fails?

Comment: I updated the question with the output

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to escape the dollar as shown on the MSDN page on [Substitutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0.aspx#DollarSign).

> The $$ substitution inserts a literal "$" character in the replaced string.

So you want:

```
string replacementString = "some text $$0.00";
```

As an aside, please don't use try/catch blocks like that... it clutters up your code for no benefit.

Answer (score 0):

You should escape `$` literal, e.g.: `$$`. Also, if you want to replace only `this is what I want to replace` is better to use regexp:

```
(?<=\[BEGIN-LOOP:DETAILS\]).*?(?=\[END-LOOP:DETAILS\])
```

Answer (score 0):

As Kirill Polishchuk already pointed out, you should use a different search pattern. This pattern matches a position between a prefix and a suffix:

```
(?<=prefix)find(?=suffix)
```

Applied to your problem, the pattern would look like this:

```
(?<=\[BEGIN-LOOP:DETAILS]).*?(?=\[END-LOOP:DETAILS])
```